# On hover of link change fill of separate SVG polygon

Tags: css, svg

I have a list of rooms in the left hand column and an SVG floor plan in the right column. I have two questions:

Is there a way of me changing the colour of a room in the floor plan when a link in the left column is rolled over using pure CSS?

If the answer is no, what approach do I take? I'm guessing some sort of JS but don't know where to start or what to search for.

Here's a working example of where I'm up to so far:

```css
div#list {float:left; width:50%}
div#list ul li a {color:#333}
div#list ul li a:hover {color:#ED5D45}
div#map {float:right; width:50%}
div#map svg#plan polygon.building {fill:#CCC}
div#map svg#plan a polygon.studio-j {fill:#333}
div#map svg#plan a:hover polygon.studio-j {fill:#ED5D45}
```

```html
<div id="list">
  <ul>
    <li class="j"><a href="/studios/j/">Studio J</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="map">
<svg id="plan" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 412 408" enable-background="new 0 0 412 408" xml:space="preserve">  
  <polygon class="building" points="0,68.1 377.2,0 411,407.3 20,405.7 "/>
  <a xlink:href="/studios/j/" xlink:title="Studio J">
    <polygon class="studio-j" points="214,126 261,126 261,131 388,131 377.2,0.4 213.5,30.2 "/>
  </a>
</svg>
</div>
```

Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/morgyface/7utpx1n6/

Comment: As broad help or even a nudge in the right direction were apparently "off-topic" for anyone else reading this I finally solved it using CSS, jquery and .hover and .toggleClass.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with CSS given the structure as the link is not related to the SVG.

JS would be needed which would simplify the issue.

Alternatively, just put the links inside the `#map` div (without the list structure) and adjust the CSS accordingly.

```css
a:hover {
  color: red
}
div#map {
  float: right;
  width: 50%
}
div#map svg#plan polygon.building {
  fill: #CCC
}
svg#plan a polygon.studio-j {
  fill: #333
}
svg#plan a:hover polygon.studio-j {
  fill: #ED5D45
}
.j:hover + svg#plan a polygon.studio-j {
  fill: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="map">
  <a class="j" href="/studios/j/">Studio J</a>

  <svg id="plan" x="0" y="0" viewBox="0 0 412 408" enable-background="new 0 0 412 408" xml:space="preserve">
    <polygon class="building" points="0,68.1 377.2,0 411,407.3 20,405.7 " />
    <a xlink:href="/studios/j/" xlink:title="Studio J">
      <polygon class="studio-j" points="214,126 261,126 261,131 388,131 377.2,0.4 213.5,30.2 " />
    </a>

  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. Unfortunately I can't restructure. Can you give me any broad guidance on how to use JS to resolve?

Comment: Unfortunately, broad questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow. I'm sure you can do some searching here and via Google that might offer some insight.

Comment: How incredibly helpful sir. I would've preferred, "I can't really give you any in-depth advice but check out the JS functions X or X" but there you go, you can't always get what you want. Back to square one as I have no idea what to search for to begin with.

Comment: See the "Related Questions" over on the right? That should get you started.